# In the container the script need to add a route but its failing with error :ip: RTNETLINK answers: Operation not permitted

Tags: linux, bash, network-programming, containers, nic

The script has to add the route in the container , but the route add command is failing with below error .

`ip: RTNETLINK answers: Operation not permitted`

The above command run as a non-root user

```
bash-5.1$ /sbin/ip route add 9.0.0.0/8 via 10.196.226.1 dev eth0
ip: RTNETLINK answers: Operation not permitted
bash-5.1$ id
uid=(p2-user) 
bash-5.1$ exit
exit
```

when we run the same command as a root getting below error.

```
/ # /sbin/ip route add 9.0.0.0/8 via 10.196.226.1 dev eth0
ip: RTNETLINK answers: File exists
```